Is there a faster method than to.("cuda") that transfer model from cpu to gpu?
Below is my code. Since my idea need the self.model restore to the origin_model many times during training, and self.model would become a smaller model in the following process (nn.Linear(in, out) -> nn.Linear(in//2, out//2) for example), so I kept a duplicate origin_model in the cpu to complete the need.
self.model = copy.deepcopy(origin_model)
torch.cuda.empty_cache()
self.model = self.model.to(device=device, dtype=torch.bfloat16)

But when the model become a larger one, like LLaMA2-7B, the time that .to("cuda") would cost a lot like 10 seconds, and when doing many times it would cost a lot of time. Does anyone have a good idea to solve this problems?
The following methods also cost 11 seconds,
del self.model
torch.cuda.empty_cache()
self.model = torch.load("model.pt")

due to the torch.cuda.empty_cache() would cost another 1 more second.

Is your GPU memory to limited to keep the original model on GPU as well?

Why are you deleting and reloading the model? That's likely i/o time loading weights from disk, not moving tensors to the GPU.

Yes, my gpu can only support one model, so I kept the original model on the cpu memory

I delete and reload the model because in the following code, the model will be pruned in a new and smaller size and trained for some steps. And in a new epoch I want do the same things, so I delete the model and make it a new one.

The most time-costly thing I haves tested, is the .to(‘cuda’) or load operation, but the copy or del would not cost a lot.
